# How to Include a HTML file outside my web-application into a JSP inside my application

Tags: jsp, jspinclude, page-directives

I have a HTML Page at a Web Publisher whose content i want to load in a JSP inside my web application. I have tried **JSP:Include** action and **Include directive** but both of them seem to take only relative path. I cannot have a local copy of that html file because that is subject to changes in future and i  need to include it dynamically. How to include a file using an absolute path?

Comment: You can't call a JSP that is on another server - calling a JSP from external server returns the *generated* page (HTML) - not the source code! Just copy the JSP to your server and include it using a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

The JSTL c:import taglib allows you to import a file from any url, http:// or file://. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/import.html

Comment: Good to hear it helped. Maybe you could also accept the answer or upvote it?